# Can WiX source refer to NuGet packages from another projects in solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, nuget, wix3.6

I have a solution with two projects:

- .NET application
- WiX setup project.

I know, that it is possible to refer to project output in WiX source (`$(var.WindowsFormsApplication1.TargetFileName)`).

Now I've added a NuGet package reference to my .NET application. So, I want to bring NuGet package content into my setup.

Is there any way to do this instead of adding files manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there is any linkage.  I know what nuget is but I haven't used it much because it's more about brining your .NET dependencies into scope then software distribution.  Depending on how nuget lays the files down you might be able to do something like $(var.SomeProject.TargetDir)nuget_fetched.dll.

This is assuming that SomeProject uses nuget in such a way that the references are copied locally and available in the Outdir of the project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sounds bad. NuGet package content is available at solution directory after building of .NET project... This what I've meant under "adding files manually". The problem is the potential complexity of package structure - that's what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: As I understand nuget, it's all about making pulling in external components and adding them to your project in an easy way.  I don't belive they address the deployment side at all.

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it so far, because the package manager gives you the correct "flavour" of library (`net40`, `sl3`, etc.) from a package, which you'd otherwise have to hard-code or build heuristics for (in addition to accounting for package version numbers) when adding paths in the installer. That said, I've just run into the first occurrence of some package's libraries *not* being set "copy local" (but only on one developer's machine), and of course it borked the installer build when the dependencies weren't in the expected place.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Resharper live template to cut out a lot of the typing involved in adding the files, but essentially I've just added the files manually. Creating a Wix component per nuget package keep things neat.